# Iptables: limit mdns packet per second per ip

Tags: iptables, udp, mdns, connlimit

I have a network with a lot of MDNS (UDP 5353) traffic on it.

To avoid overloading my server, I limit globally the MDNS packets accepted by iptables with this rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth2 -p udp --dport 5353 -m limit --limit 100/second -j ACCEPT
```

Now I would like to set this limite per source IP, in oder to accept 5 MDNS packet per second for a single source ip.

However, I'm not sure on how to do that... With `connlimit` maybe? But because I'm working on UDP packet (without connection), I don't think its the answer here...